# Is there a jQuery Autocomplete plugin that'll force the selection of an item?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

There's *[autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete)*, but it doesn't force the selection of an item. I need something like this but it has to force an item to be selected before you can "submit".

Does it exist?

Comment: Can't you just haven an "listener" on the dropdowns 'onChange' ? Onche it has changed, it means something has been selected, and thus you can enable the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution with .blur (moreover I use name|ID pairs)

```
jQuery("#username").autocomplete(
    "/yii_app/stock/suggestUser",
    {
        'mustMatch':true,
        'multiple':false,
        'formatItem':function(result, i, num, term) {
            return '<small>'+result[1]+'</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ result[0];
        }
    }
).result(
    function(event,item) {
        $("#user_id").val(item[1]);
    }
).blur(
    function() {
        $("#user_id").val('');
        $(this).search();
    }
);
```

user_id is a hidden input field, username is an text input field
ajax result uses the following format:
user1name|user1id\n
user2name|user2id\n

Comment: I don't understand how something like this can get 4 upvotes. The call to ".result" doesn't even pass syntactical muster in Firefox. And there is a call to "search", which apparently does not even exist. So frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ["change" event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)  of Autocomplete

```
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript"
        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if(!ui.item){
                    //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                    // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                    //so clear the item for force selection
                    $("#tags").val("");
                }

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the option:

```
mustMatch:true,
```

This is available in the Bassistance autocomplete plugin. Ii do not know if it is a part of jQuery autocomplete or of Bassistance's autocomplete, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution using [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI)'s [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

```
    $('#some-input').autocomplete({
        source: 'some-url',
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            //remember the selected item
            $('#some-input')
                .data('selected-item', ui.item.label);
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var value = $('#some-input').val();
        //check if the input's value matches the selected item
        if(value != $('#some-input').data('selected-item')) {
            //they don't, the user must have typed something else
            $('#some-input')
                .val('') //clear the input's text
                .data('selected-item', ''); //clear the selected item
        }
    });
```

Each time the blur event is triggered, the input's value is checked to have been picked previously. If it hasn't been picked (you know that because the select event never triggered), the 'selected-item' variable will not match the input's value. Then you can do whatever you want (I clear the input, but you can try something else).

Comment: If you add $("#some-input').val(ui.item.label); to the select call, your solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in combination with the [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.  Just make the field `required` for the validation plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built in submit event

```
$('Autocomplete').autocomplete({
          select: function(event, ui) {
                       $('submit').show();
                  }
});
```