# How to force a user to select values only from autocomplete popup

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI autocomplete for zipcode text field.I want to force user to select only zipcode that are coming in autocomplete options.

Before Asking this questions I have searched a lot on above question But I didnt get any solution for my scenario.

Actually I am using Ajax call to get json response from www.geonames.org site
which has responses with zipcode ,state ,city & some other values.

My problem is that I am unable to implement functionality which will force user to select values only from autocomplete.

How to do it any hints and answer are helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

*You might want to think of the UX implications of using an autocomplete to restrict a user's input on a field. More often than not, these types of controls are used to help suggest possibilities, not restrict. Think of goggle suggest as an example.*

However, to answer the question. You could check the value of the input against the returned results from the autocomplete on `blur` to make sure that it matches at least one of them. I found [a working example of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/EuXrP/).

The other popular way to do it is to populate a hidden form element that is only populated by the autocomplete `result` event:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585868/159341